# org.edx.mobile.util.images.ErrorUtils: org.edx.mobile.http.HttpStatusException: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=}

Tags: android, android-studio, openedx

I am trying to configure the Open edX Android app https://github.com/edx/edx-app-android using Android Studio.

The point given below is also set.

- Create `edx.properties` inside the `OpenEdXMobile` directory.

  ```
  edx.dir = '../../my_config'
  ```
- Create `edx.properties` inside the `my_config` directory.

  ```
  edx.android {
     configFiles = ['android.yaml']
  }
  ```
- Create `android.yaml` file inside the `my_config` directory.

  ```
  API_HOST_URL: 'https://org.mylms.com'
  ENVIRONMENT_DISPLAY_NAME: 'Training Potal'
  OAUTH_CLIENT_ID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  PLATFORM_NAME: 'Training'
  USER_PROFILES_ENABLED: 'true'
  PLATFORM_DESTINATION_NAME: 'org.mylms.com'
  ```
- Create `gradle.properties` file inside the `OpenEdXMobile` directory.

  ```
  APPLICATION_ID=org.edx.mobile
  RELEASE_STORE_FILE=../../openedx.keystore
  RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=mystorepassword
  RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=mykeypassword
  RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=openedx_alias
  ```

I am getting below error after login successfully in the Android App.

```
E/org.edx.mobile.util.images.ErrorUtils: org.edx.mobile.http.HttpStatusException: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=https://org.mylms.com/api/mobile/v1/users/staff/course_enrollments}
        at org.edx.mobile.http.util.CallUtil.executeStrict(CallUtil.java:51)
        at org.edx.mobile.loader.CoursesAsyncLoader.loadInBackground(CoursesAsyncLoader.java:52)
        at org.edx.mobile.loader.CoursesAsyncLoader.loadInBackground(CoursesAsyncLoader.java:22)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:307)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:60)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:48)
        at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:141)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: are you sure you are using correct link? It says the link is "https://org.mylms.com/api/mobile/v1/users/staff/course_enrollments" which doesn't exist

Comment: I have hidden the sensitive information as per the StackOverflow policy. I have hidden my domain only, all information is correct.

Comment: have you checked that the link you actually use in your app opens the image?

Comment: Yes, It is showing Page not found error.

Comment: have you tried opening it in your pc browser?

Comment: Yes, I have tried in pc browser, It is showing Page not found error.

Comment: Maybe, It is an API version issue.